# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, defaultdict

```
 def_dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: np.array([np.array([-1, 1]), np.array([-1, 1])]))
 def_dictionary[tuple([3,5])][1] = np.concatenate((def_dictionary[tuple([3, 5])][1], np.array([6])))
```

How should I append an integer to `def_dictionary[tuple([3,5])][1]` array? I tried np.append but it has the same problem. There's probably some easy workaround. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does the right hand side of the `=` work?  Try the `concatenate` alone, without the assignment.  It may be that you are trying to put a 3 element array into a 2 element slot.

Comment: Right hand side works both for `np.append` and `np.concatenate'

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change `def_dictionary[tuple([3,5])][1]`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change shape of an element of an array. Hence I had to get rid of array of arrays. I workaround this by creating defaultdic with defaultdic in it:

```
def_dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: np.array([-1, 1])))
```